# Adding Response Header to Growthbook call

Tags: reactjs, x-frame-options, growthbook

I want the Growthbook calls to include a header in their response "x-frame-option".

This is the way i am initializing growthbook in my frontend code:

```
import { GrowthBook } from "@growthbook/growthbook";

// Create a GrowthBook instance
const gb = new GrowthBook({
  apiHost: "https://cdn.growthbook.io",
  clientKey: "sdk-abc123",
  // Enable easier debugging during development
  enableDevMode: true,
});

useEffect(() => {
  // Load features from the GrowthBook API
  growthbook.loadFeatures({ autoRefresh: true });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // Set user attributes for targeting (from cookie, auth system, etc.)
  growthbook.setAttributes({
    tenantId: process.env.TENANT_ID,
  });
}, []);
```

This is the screenshot of response headers that i get from the call:

[image]

Can someone help me on how to get growthbook to include x-frame-options in their response headers